# How can I retrieve value from a string of list of map

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, user-interface

I have some requirement like I need to get the values from a map actually where the format is as below:

`"{xyz=True, abc=asd-1123, uvw=null}"`

to get the values from this map which is in string.

I tried to use `JSON.parse("{xyz=True, abc=asd-1123, uvw=null}")` and also tried using `var map = new Map(JSON.parse("{xyz=True, abc=asd-1123, uvw=null}"))`

But neither way it was not working

Comment: It's invalid json, invalid javascript, and apart from one constant string you didn't specify anything, so i think it'll be both hard to do, and even harder to answer.

Comment: Well it's not valid JSON, so that is not a surprise. Why is the string in that format? Where does it come from?

Comment: I am setting  a map in session using `session.setAttribute()`  in java server side piece of code then trying to get this value from js file. Even if I got that from session in JS, it seems  very difficult to retrieve this values.

Comment: 1. Encode that value as JSON on the server-side. 2. Parse JSON on the client. 3. Done.

Answer (score 0):

well to start, json.parse is not going to work as that is not valid json. you are going to need to do the parsing yourself. So assuming everything is consistently in that method, you should start by stripping off the curly braces then breaking down your values and creating your map from those values.

So as an example:

```
let map = new Map(); // or create an object: {}, because you can get values using Object.values(yourObject)
let mapStr = "{xyz=True, abc=asd-1123, uvw=null}".slice(1, -1);
let kvp = mapStr.split(', ');
for(let i = 0; i < kvp.length; i++) {
   let splitVal = kvp[i].split(=);
   map.set(splitVal[0], splitVal[1]);
}
```

Then you can just use the map object you created.

Take into consideration this assumes none of your key-value-pairs have an "=" sign in them. you can also further investigate regexs to generate your maps. either way, it's on you to do the mapping unless there is a library that does this for you already in existence :)

Comment: you are right, it should be map.set(...) but it does sort of work that way :P 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Only in that is is an object and you can add properties to just about any object. Wouldn't be able to use `get()` that way